# Equation for position and velocity of a body falling in a gravitational field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-fall

I have tried asking this question on many forums and have so far failed to get a clear answer. Here is the problem. A body with a negligible mass is falling from a distance $R_1$ in a gravitational field of a another body with a mass of $M$. What would be the position $R_2$ of the falling body after $t$ amount of time. Conversely, how long would it take for the falling body to travel the distance R1-R2?

Since the gravitational acceleration $g(M,R)$ is a function of distance $R$, the falling body should experience jerk. Would the jerk itself be constant? What is the equation for this jerk?

I want an equation that clearly shows the relationship between **position** (distance from the source of gravity), **mass** (of the source of gravity and **time** (that has elapse since the start of the fall) WITHOUT assuming that g = constant. All equations I could get assume g(R,M) is not a function of R and that is not what I want.

I am looking for two clear formulae:
-for **time** as a function of distance and mass,
-for **distance** as a function of time and mass

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall#Inverse-square_law_gravitational_field) gives time as a function of position for radial freefall under inverse-square gravity. There are *many* previous questions on this site about this.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14700/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63590/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140902/discussion-on-question-by-iam-cleaver-equation-for-position-and-velocity-of-a-bo).