# Third Kepler's Law and Collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, potential

I have to solve the following problem:

Two particles of masses $m_a=m$ and $m_b=2m$ interact by gravitational forces

$$\vec{F}_{ab}=-G\frac{m_am_b\vec{r}}{r^3} \; ,\qquad \vec{F}_{ba}=-\vec{F}_{ab}$$

where $\vec{r}$ is the relative position of $a$ on $b$. ¿When will they collide?

That's the problem. Then, the author gives a clue: Use the third Kepler's law for an elliptic orbit in the limit $L \rightarrow 0$ (angular momentum)?

Well, I tried to write the third Kepler's law in terms of $L$ to calculate the limit, but I can't. Is there another way to do it?

The solution is

$$t_c=\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2 d^3}{24Gm}}.$$

Comment: See [Radial Motion of Two Mutually Attracting Particles](https://www.usna.edu/Users/physics/mungan/_files/documents/Publications/TPT17.pdf).

Comment: @sammygerbil -- Nice find. [Pulsar's answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90722/52112) explicitly invokes Kepler's third law, making this question a duplicate.