# How to solve Newton's Law of Gravitation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Imagine you have Newton's Law of gravitation.
How would you solve this differential equation.
$$
\frac{\mathrm d^2 r(t)}{\mathrm d t^2 } =-\frac{GM}{r(t)^2}
$$

I know the solution of this equation is a conic section, but how would you arrive to that? Also, I know that the final result is a function $r(\theta)$ not $r(t)$, but why? I've tried to search on the internet but I feel like they don't explain too much the process. I would like, if possible, a way of understanding each of the steps of the derivation.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tSmY4fn5xY) may answer some of your questions.

Comment: Check the solutions here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14700/

Comment: Solve for what? Orbits or free fall?

Comment: See Sec. 4.1 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_central-force_problem), but you may need to read earlier sections as well.