# Gravitational collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, time, free-fall

Two point particles of exactly the same m = mass 1kg is separated by a distance of d = 4m. After how much time, they will collide with each other due to the force of gravity?

Assume that, the gravitational constant G = 1

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14700/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Time That 2 Masses Will Collide Due To Newtonian Gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14700/)

Comment: What is the initial relative velocity of the particles ? This is an important condition.