# Free Fall with non-constant acceleration due to gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-fall

In a free fall motion, the height of the falling object is constantly changing and its acceleration due to gravity is also changing.

However, we usually ignore the effects of changes in height on the acceleration due to gravity because the change in height is too small compared to the radius of the earth. Suppose we now take this small change into account, making the acceleration due to gravity ($g$) a non-constant value in the free fall. Given the time the object takes to fall to the ground (where the distance to the center of the earth is exactly the earth's radius) and its mass, how can we find the height that it fell from (displacement)?

I first wanted to start by writing the acceleration ($g$) as a function of height ($r$) and displacement as a function of time ($t$).

$$v(t) = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} a(t) \ \mathrm{d}t, \quad d(t) = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} v(t) \ \mathrm{d}t, \quad g(r) = \frac{GM}{r^2}.$$

But I do not have any clues about the next step. I attempted to find a relationship between $r$ and $t$, but it did not work. I was wondering if this problem is solvable by only using single variable calculus, or more advanced mathematics is required.

Comment: This is known as [Kepler's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_problem). It can be solved using single variable calculus, but it is not particularly obvious

Comment: Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) instead.

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_trajectory & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14700/123208

Answer (score 2):

So, you can use conservation of energy,

$$GMm(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{h})=\frac{1}{2}mv^2\implies v=\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{h} \frac{h-r}{r}}$$

But v is also $-\frac{dr}{dt}$,so we can integrate to get:

$$\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{h}}t=\int_r^h \sqrt{\frac{r}{h-r}}=\sqrt{hr-r^2}+h\arctan{\sqrt{\frac{h-r}{r}}}$$

So, the time taken and height of dropping we can get r and vice versa.  Hope this answers your question and let me know  if you need more detail

Comment: Note that r,h are distances from center of earth and notsurface

Comment: The first line makes sense. In the second line of the equation, did you take the integral of velocity w/r to time in order to find the displacement? If so, could you explain the calculation in a little more detail?

Comment: @Yunoix So essentially what I did was, I wrote the velocity as a function of radius, using conservation of energy. But we also know velocity is the rate of change of displacement, and try to think of change in displacement as the negative of change in radius. so v=-dr/dt, take all terms independent independent of r to one side, and all terms independent of t to other side and integrate. We have now successfully eliminated velocity, and the equation is only in terms of radius and time.