# Time taken for an object to fall

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, time, free-fall

Time taken for an object to fall is generally given by $$t=\sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}}.$$ But this is only true under the assumption that gravitational acceleration is constant. With variable gravity what would be the formula for time taken for an object to fall a distance of $h$. [I've tried using elliptical orbits and calculus for this as well but could not seem to get it.]

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14700/2451 and links therein.