Deceleration over time, not distance, when a body was launched at escape velocity
Say I fire/launch some projectile straight up at escape velocity (ignoring drag, etc). Computing it's deceleration over distance is easy, but what about over time? I can't find anything on that. I tried to figure it out starting with an imaginary planet with a radius of one, an acceleration of gravity at the surface of one, and came up with:
t=(2/(3d))^(1/3)
... which sorta smells right, but I'm not at all sure my calculus is correct.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/14707/55662

Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_trajectory

Thanks, that's meat to chew on.  Seems I'm 'warm' at least.  the '2/3' fraction is there but I use the '1/3' power ... I'll dig into it.
